# How to record streaming camera video and auto-erase old data before drive fills up?

Tags: webcam, camera, storage, stream, video-recording

I'm interested in making my own home CCTV system using Ubuntu. I want to get network cameras similar to [this on eBay](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=260745150596).

I want a way to dump or record the live stream to a large hard drive, but have Ubuntu automatically delete the oldest parts of the video while the drive fills, so it can continue recording new data continuously.

How can this auto-delete while recording be accomplished? I've searched and searched.

Comment: are you looking for a specific CCTV software or are you trying to design your own video management system?

Comment: S/w. I think I've found what I think I need, ZoneMinder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting user's response so someone can vote this up and we can mark
this post as resolved.

"S/w. I think I've found what I think I need, ZoneMinder"

Comment: In the end I went for Motion, miles better for my needs.